# autolayout UILabel's dynamic height calculation doesn't work when text is empty string?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel, uitableviewautomaticdimension

in iOS 8, I have a `UILabel` in a `UITableViewCell`. I want the cell to have dynamic height according to `UILabel`'s text. It works fine. **But when the text is a empty string, it seems has a default height, but I want it to be zero.**

Here is what I've done:

1. set cell's constraints using `masonry`. set `top`, `bottom` constraint.
2. set `tableView.estimatedHeight`
3. return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for `heightForRow` delegate method

So did I do anything wrong? Any help?

Comment: [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];  [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded]; add this two method also set labelcentral vertically so you dont need to give top and bottom space so you have to set leading space to margin from where u required

Answer (score 2):

Change your code for heightForRowAtIndexPath to this. This works!

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   NSString *text = [yourDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   if(text.length > 0 ){
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
[yourLabel setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

Set your label V compress to a high priority